# Why does the focused input text lose its focus?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I've got this at the bottom of my ready function:

```
$("inputText").focus();
```

...and as the page is loading, the cursor *is* in the inputText input Text for awhile, but then focus is lost again. What could be causing this, and how do I force the focus to stay there?

### UPDATE

I wondered if "raw" Javascript would make any difference:

```
document.getElementById("inputText").focus();
```

It doesn't.

Maybe this is a known problem; when you go to amazon, you would think the cursor would give focus to the search input text, but it doesn't - I always have to click in, which I think is rather lame. Yet, it works for Bing, so it's obviously possible.

Comment: And if you put your code at the bottom of the window.onload handler, same issue? Or using HTML5 autofocus attribute?

Comment: `$("inputText")` means select all "inputText" tags. I think you mean to select by class: `$(".inputText")` or by id: `$("#inputText")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that your real code? Is your selector really `inputText`? In that case, that's probably the problem.

My guess is that the input is focused automatically first. Then the document ready handler kicks in and looks for a a tag `inputText` which I suppose you don't have. I guess you have `<input id="inputText" />`, which is selected with `$("#inputText")` so the selector doesn't find anything and moves the focus away from the input.

An additional check since you've tagged this asp.net. Are you using web forms? In that case html ids are not reliable since the web forms engine mess upp the ids - use a css class intead and a `$(".inputText")` selector.

Comment: Maybe its relative to browser behaviour but at least on chrome, setting focus() to a empty jquery object has no effect

Comment: @roasted - I am using Chrome. There is a placeholder value in #inputText, but that may be considered empty...

Comment: @Anders Abel: Did you hear that "thunk"? That was me kicking myself in the kneecap because I forgot the "#" again. But, adding it made no difference. Maybe it is a Chrome thing.

Comment: I tried on IE 10 and Firefox. On both, the focus works; however, on IE 10, whenever I submit the form, IE crashes. On firefox, it doesn't crash, but my iframes are all punily-sized. IOW, none of the three work quite like I want them to.

Comment: @roasted: No, autofocus doesn't work, either:
<input type="text" name="inputText" id="inputText" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter something, already!" value="@Request["inputText"]" autofocus style="display: inline-block;" />

Answer (score 1):

Try using window load

```
$(window).load(function () {
```

// run code
});

It will mean the whole page has loaded then your code will run and should put focus in the input field. Here is the link to documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @VOX: For whatever reason, adding the following:
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("#inputText").focus();
        }
...whether inside the ready function or out, hoses up the whole works: the tabs no longer work (they revert to a simple ul, and all the tab contents display vertically.